# How to Save Login Session in mega.py?

Tags: python, authentication, session

**Please How Can I Save my Login in Mega account (Save Session) and reuse it
Thanks!**

My Code :

```
from mega import Mega

mega = Mega()

account = mega.login("here_email","here_passowrd")

print(account.get_files())
```

I need login again without use email and password again it's Available?

Answer (score 0):

So something like this maybe? Writes and reads from text files so you won't have to write the password and/or email each time

```
with open("email.txt", "r") as read_email :
    email = read_email.read().strip()
with open("password.txt", "r") as read_password :
    password = read_password.read().strip()


def save_info():
    with open("email.txt", "w") as f :
        f.write(input('Email: '))
    with open("password.txt", "w") as f :
        f.write(input('Password: '))

    with open("email.txt", "r") as read_email :
        email = read_email.read().strip()
    with open("password.txt", "r") as read_password :
        password = read_password.read().strip()
    print('\nemail: ' + email, '\npassword: ' + password)


credentials = input(f'Email = {email} \npassword = {password}. \nEdit login credentials press Y. \nTo continue press N: ')
if credentials == 'y'.lower():
    save_info()
else:
    # something
    print(email, password)
    # something else

> 1st run:
> /home/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python
> /home/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/LysAlarm/test.py Email = 123 
> password = 4.  Edit login credentials press Y.  To continue press N: y
> Email: hei123@gmail.com Password: lololol1234
> 
> email: hei123@gmail.com  password: lololol1234
> 
> Process finished with exit code 0
> 
> 
> 2nd run:
> 
> /home/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python
> /home/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/LysAlarm/test.py Email =
> hei123@gmail.com  password = lololol1234.  Edit login credentials
> press Y.  To continue press N: n hei123@gmail.com lololol1234
> 
> Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks But I mean login again without email and password same Token or cookies to login again Because Mega send Email every login

Answer (score 0):

You can `pickle` the Mega client object, save it to a file, and load it later to continue using the same login session.

Example:

```py
import pickle
import mega

SESSION_CACHE = 'mega_session.pickle'
MEGA_USER = 'person@example.com'
MEGA_PASSWORD = 'pAsSwOrD'

def get_mega_client():
    """
    Load Mega session from filename and return the client.
    If no session is available, return None.
    """
    try:
        with open(SESSION_CACHE, 'rb') as f:
            mega_client = pickle.load(f)
        # Quick call to trigger a RequestError if the session is expired
        mega_client.get_quota()
        print("Successfully loaded saved Mega session")
        return mega_client
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("No saved Mega session")
        pass
    except mega.errors.RequestError:
        print("Saved Mega session was bad")
        pass

    # We didn't get a good client. Generate a new one, cache
    # it in the file, and return it.
    print("Generating new Mega login session")
    mega_client = mega.Mega()
    mega_client.login(MEGA_USER, MEGA_PASSWORD)
    with open(SESSION_CACHE, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(mega_client, f)
    return mega_client


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mega_client = get_mega_client()
    print("Your current storage is:")
    print(mega_client.get_storage_space())
```

This comes with the usual warnings that [pickle is insecure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), but it should be okay in this case. I doubt Mega's credentials will get weaponised against it. :)

I see you raised a [feature request](https://github.com/odwyersoftware/mega.py/issues/45) for this but it doesn't seem to have much love. It would be nice if the mega.py authors would write a serialize() method.